# Date prompt in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

My task is to create a report with a date prompt.

Table structure is like this:

```
Name --- Valid_from --- Valid_till
------------------------------------
Smth1 --- 2001-01-01 --- 2003-03-03 
Smth2 --- 2002-02-02 --- 2004-04-04
```

Person should be promoted to enter **one** date and report should show records that was valid that day.

Environment: Crystal Reports 2008 and Oracle database.

Comment: Well what have you tried?  If you have added the table, it is a simple matter to add a parameter to get a required date.  Then you just need to add a selection with the `valid_from` data `<=` to the parameter, and the `valid_till` date `<` the parameter.

Comment: @Orbling, correct me if im wrong, but i think you meant date >= valid_from and date < valid_till

Comment: @zach: I wrote the conditions from the other perspective, but do have the second one round the wrong way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Given a date parameter named `{?DateParameter}`, you could set your selection criteria to be something like this:

```
{?DateParameter} between Valid_from and Valid_till
```